# After making a POST request to my heroku endpoint and saved it to my mongoDB, the data only shows if I refresh the page

Tags: vue.js, post, crud

I deployed my Vue app to Netlify and the backend  to heroku. Everything works fine, I can edit, delete and get data from my database, except when I submit the form (creating a new client) and I redirect to `this.$router.push("/tabela");` . The data is created, but when I go to the ListComponent.vue (path:'tabela') my data isn't there. It only shows when I refresh the page. Before deploying to heroku, I fixed the issue with `window.location.href="/tabela";` instead `this.$router.push` but now, If I use `window.location.href="/tabela"` I cannot save to my database anymore. I need to use `this.$router.push` in order to make it "work" but as I said, then I need to refresh the page to update my table with the new client.
Here is my app https://cadastro-app.netlify.app/ .

CreateComponent.vue

```
methods: {
            submitForm(){
               
                if(this.cliente.cpf === ''){
                    this.cliente.cpf = 'Não Informado'
                }else if(this.cliente.cnpj === ''){
                    this.cliente.cnpj = 'Não Informado'
                }

                axios.post('https://cadastro-backend-app.herokuapp.com/clientes', {
                    data: this.cliente
                }).then(function(){     
                    
                    this.cliente = {
                        nome: '',
                        sobrenome: '',
                        email: '',
                        telefone: '',
                        cnpj: '',
                        cpf: ''
                    }                 

                }).catch(function (error) {
                    console.log(error);
                });

                 /* window.location.href="/tabela"; */
                this.$router.push("/tabela"); 
                                 
            }
        }
```

ListComponent.vue

```
    <template>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12 ">   
            
            <div class="search">
                <input @keyup.enter.prevent="search()" v-model='nomePesquisado' class="form-control mb-3" type="text"  placeholder="Pesquisar" aria-label="Search"/>
            </div>

            <table class="table table-striped">
                <thead class="thead-dark">
                    <tr>
                        <th>Nome completo</th>
                        <th>Email</th>
                        <th>telefone</th>
                        <th>CNPJ</th>
                        <th>CPF</th>
                        <th>Actions</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <tr v-for="cliente in clientes" :key="cliente._id">
                        <td>{{ cliente.nome }}</td>
                        <td>{{ cliente.email }}</td>
                        <td>{{ cliente.telefone }}</td>
                        <td>{{ cliente.cnpj }}</td>
                        <td>{{ cliente.cpf }}</td>
                        <td>
                            <router-link :to="{name: 'edit', params: { id: cliente._id }}" class="btn btn-success">Editar
                            </router-link>
                            <button @click.prevent="removerCliente(cliente._id)" class="btn btn-danger">Remover</button>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    import axios from "axios";

    export default {
        data() {
            return {
                clientes: [],
                nomePesquisado:''
            }
        },
        created() {
            let apiURL = 'https://cadastro-backend-app.herokuapp.com/clientes/';
            axios.get(apiURL).then(res => {
                this.clientes = res.data;
                console.log(this.clientes);
            }).catch(error => {
                console.log(error)
            });
        },
        methods: {
            removerCliente(id){
                const apiURL = `https://cadastro-backend-app.herokuapp.com/clientes/${id}`;
                const indexOfArrayItem = this.clientes.findIndex(i => i._id === id);

                if (window.confirm("Tem certeza que deseja remover este item?")) {
                    axios.delete(apiURL).then(() => {
                        this.clientes.splice(indexOfArrayItem, 1);
                    }).catch(error => {
                        console.log(error)
                    });
                }
            },
            search(){
                this.$router.push(`results/${this.nomePesquisado}`);
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

router index.js

```
import Vue from "vue";
import VueRouter from "vue-router";

Vue.use(VueRouter);

const routes = [
  {
    path: "/",
    name: "home",
    component: () => import("../components/CreateComponent")
  },
  {
    path: "/tabela",
    name: "tabela",
    component: () => import("../components/ListComponent")
  },
  {
    path: "/edit/:id",
    name: "edit",
    component: () => import("../components/EditComponent")
  },
  {
    path: "/results/:id",
    name: "results",
    component: () => import("../components/Results")
  }
];

const router = new VueRouter({
  mode: "history",
  base: process.env.BASE_URL,
  routes
});

export default router;
```

Comment: 1. Don't post code as pictures. Post at text with [formating](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) 2. If you say data is saved in DB, why posting server side code? Nothing interesting there. 3. You say problem is in `ListComponent`,  show it's code. Plus router configuration and component with `<router-view>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are changing the route (`this.$router.push("/tabela");`) too early

This is what is happening:

1. You make a POST request
2. Without waiting for a request to complete, you are telling Vue router to switch to `ListComponent` (`this.$router.push("/tabela");`)
3. Router activates `ListComponent` component
4. `ListComponent` runs a GET request to the server in it's `created` hook

Result is a "race". Will POST request be fast enough so the GET request sees the new data ?

To be sure, move `this.$router.push("/tabela");` inside `then`

Comment: I don't why but when I add `this.$router.push("/tabela")` and click to submit, I cannot go to my path. I've opened the console.log and went to  Network.. I see Status pending (no content) and then the status changes to failed  204 No content.

Comment: I see `Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://cadastro-backend-app.herokuapp.com/clientes' from origin 'https://cadastro-app.netlify.app' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.`

Comment: But I required cors and I'm using it on my server.js  `app.use(cors());`

Comment: Well, it's another issue. I changed my answer to be more clear about the "original" problem you asked in the question....